# How do you make money?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I've played through Chapter 3 and done the first side quest (Paralogue), and I still have the same amount of money I've had since the beginning of the game. Equipment is starting to wear down and I think I might have to buy replacements soon. How can I start collecting more money so that I have enough to cover costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to earn money is by selling items. Certain items exist only for the sake of selling and thus earning money (see [bullions](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Bullion)).

Bullions come in 3 variants

- Small - sells for 1000
- Medium - sells for 5000
- Large - sells for 10000

The way to get these items is by fighting.

After Chapter 3, you can buy the reeking box item. On normal, it only costs 500, and it's well worth the investment.

With this item, you can summon undead, to fight against them. These fights usually yield at least 1 bullion and sometimes other items (weapons, tomes, staffs etc.). They are also good to make your units stronger.

Comment: And usually at least one enemy worth a massive amount of XP.